# Keep a character found by preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, uppercase

I want to replace a dot followed by a space followed by a uppercase and I tried this pattern to replace it by `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`:

```
preg_replace('/\. [A-Z]/', '.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 'With marriage came a move to the beautiful Birmingham, Alabama area. Diving in head first.');
```

It's working but I am loosing the D of Diving in head first.

How can I keep it?

Comment: `'/\.\s+(?=[A-Z])/'`

Comment: preg_replace('/\. ([A-Z])/', '.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $1',$s );
$s is your string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the letter matching pattern into a non-consuming lookahead:

```
'/\.\s+(?=[A-Z])/'
```

The `\s+` will match 1 or more whitespaces (or if you do not want that, keep the regular space) and `(?=[A-Z])` makes the engine require an uppercase ASCII letter to appear right after the current location in the string.

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/5N5AQd) printing `With marriage came a move to the beautiful Birmingham, Alabama area.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Diving in head first.`.